# About the "tic-tac-toe squirrel challenge"

Tags: candy-box-2

Squirrel plays tic-tac-toe at expert level and is a formidable player.

Has anyone managed to win?

Tried following this: http://www.wikihow.com/Win-at-Tic-Tac-Toe but its always a draw.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are all the correct answers to the Squirrel's questions, and what is the reward when I get them all correct?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/137242/what-are-all-the-correct-answers-to-the-squirrels-questions-and-what-is-the-re)

Comment: I believe this shouldn't be closed as a duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/137242/what-are-all-the-correct-answers-to-the-squirrels-questions-and-what-is-the-re as per community consensus in the [meta] post, [What do you do when a question is asked which is a collection of other asked questions?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7901/4797)

Answer (score 18):

Try thinking outside the box.. *(hover below to see solution)*

> You can place your X outside the boundaries.

Comment: You beat me to it.

Comment: for those who don't play, I guess it means putting an X outside the "official" playing area

Answer (score 0):

The Only way to win is by putting all of you X's in a row outside the box.